# The geometric intepretation behind introducing auxiliary function in weak maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

When proving weak maximum principle, for example $\Delta u\geq 0$, to get a contradiction, we need to introduce an auxiliary function e.x. $v=\epsilon e^{x_1}$, to make $\Delta (u+v)>0$. I am wondering what is the geometric sense behind introducing this auxiliary function?

Answer (score 0):

What is the geometric sense of $\Delta u >0$ ?

Comment: convex function

Comment: f is said to be convex if its hessian is positive defined.